# HSI image is equalized incorrectly in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have implemented equalization for HSI color based images. I used numpy and math modules.

Firstly, I convert RGB image into HSI using this functions:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def rgb2hsi_px(px):
    eps = 0.00000001

    r, g, b = float(px[0]) / 255, float(px[1]) / 255, float(px[2]) / 255

    # Hue component
    numerator = 0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b))
    denominator = math.sqrt((r - g) ** 2 + (r - b) * (g - b))
    theta = math.acos(numerator / (denominator + eps))
    h = theta
    if b > g:
        h = 2 * math.pi - h

    # Saturation component
    num = min(r, g, b)
    den = r + g + b
    if den == 0:
        den = eps
    s = 1 - 3 * num / den
    if s == 0:
        h = 0

    # Intensity component
    i = (r + g + b) / 3

    return h, s, i


def rgb2hsi(image):
    hsi_image = np.zeros_like(image).astype('float')
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    for x in range(height):
        for y in range(width):
            px = rgb2hsi_px(image[x, y])
            hsi_image[x, y] = px
    return np.array(hsi_image)
```

Then I equalize an intensity value of converted image. The `equalize` function was implemented using [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00108.pdf):

```
import math
import numpy as np

def equalize(img):
    eps = 0.000000000001
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    num_of_pxs = h * w
    mean = 0.0
    new_img = np.array(img)
    while not abs(mean - 0.5) < eps:
        for i in range(h):
            for j in range(w):
                mean += new_img[i, j, 2]
        mean /= num_of_pxs
        if mean != 0.5:
            theta = math.log(0.5, math.e) / math.log(mean, math.e)
            for x in range(h):
                for y in range(w):
                    px = list(new_img[x, y])
                    px[2] = (px[2] ** theta)
                    new_img[x, y] = px
    return new_img
```

After, I convert HSI image back to RGB using the next code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

def hsi2rgb_px(px):
    h, s, i = float(px[0]), float(px[1]), float(px[2]) * 255
    if 0 <= h < 2 * math.pi / 3:
        b = i * (1 - s)
        r = i * (1 + (s * math.cos(h)) / math.cos(math.pi / 3 - h))
        g = 3 * i - (r + b)
    elif 2 * math.pi / 3 <= h < 4 * math.pi / 3:
        r = i * (1 - s)
        g = i * (1 + (s * math.cos(h - 2 * math.pi / 3) / math.cos(math.pi / 3 - (h - 2 * math.pi / 3))))
        b = 3 * i - (r + g)
    elif 4 * math.pi / 3 <= h <= 2 * math.pi:
        g = i * (1 - s)
        b = i * (1 + (s * math.cos(h - 4 * math.pi / 3) / math.cos(math.pi / 3 - (h - 4 * math.pi / 3))))
        r = 3 * i - (g + b)
    else:
        raise IndexError('h is out of range: {}'.format(h))
    return round(r), round(g), round(b)


def hsi2rgb(image):
    rgb_image = np.zeros_like(image).astype(np.uint8)
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    for x in range(height):
        for y in range(width):
            px = hsi2rgb_px(image[x, y])
            rgb_image[x, y] = px
    return np.array(rgb_image)
```

But an equalization gives an incorrect result. The size (in megabytes) of equalized image is larger than the original one. I'm not sure if it's normal but if yes, please, let me know. And another problem is that an output image has worse quality.

Here is an original image:

[image]

And the equalized image:

[image]

Can someone help me to fix my code, or reference me to similar article/question?

[UPDATE]

Driver program to test an algorithm:

```
import matplotlib.image as mp_img

input_img = mp_img.imread('input.bmp')

hsi_img = rgb2hsi(input_img)
equalized_img = equalize(hsi_img)
out_img = hsi2rgb(equalized_img)

mp_img.imsave('out.bmp', out_img)
```

Comment: You seem to have cut out all the `import` statements and everything to do with loading and saving the image - so nobody can run it to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added driver program to test the code.

Comment: I don't have a computer close by, but I have a couple of questions that may help you solve the problem: 1. Have you tested your equalisation with grey scale images? 2. Have you tested to see if the magnitude of `px - hsi2rgb_px(rgb2hsi_px(px))` is small?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Grey scale image become violet without converting it to HSI, otherwise become lighter. The magnitude of `px - hsi2rgb_px(rgb2hsi_px(px))` is 0.

Comment: Is this what you were aiming for? http://thesetchells.com/StackOverflow/58531390.png

Comment: Mark Setchell, yes.